# How to find the order of recipe files for an image in bitbake

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Is there a way to list down the order of recipes parsed for an image in bitbake.

Comment: In a nutshell, no. It is totally contradictory to the concept of a recipe build being reproductible. If you got ordering problems, then find out why and solve them through correct deendency construction.

Comment: I want to know what packages have to built before I can build a crosscompiler, how can I know this ? I know that the image meta-toolchain does this. I was wondering if I could get the order in which it creates packages.

Comment: No, thats the wrong way around. Its not "build a crosscompiler if somebody needs it", but "if seomthing needs it, then build crosscompiler". The flow of control is in the opposite direction. So say you have a recipe that needs some very special cross-toolchain, then 1) make a recipe for that cross-toolchain 2) in the recipe that needs it have `DEPENDS += "spceial-crosstoolchain-native"`. Then it will be built if needed.

Comment: Oh and one more thing:: meta-toolchain almost certainly does *NOT* look at all the packages, it rather just builds a toolchain set for the MACHINE/arch combination that is configured. Plus, it is heavily outdated: rather use `-c populated_sdk` on your image.